Chandelier hanging dilema
Replacing Chandelier Issues
Hello. I'm trying to replace my foyer chandelier with a new one that weighs 110lbs. First issue is that the chandelier is 20ft up on a sloped ceiling and over a staircase. I'll have to rent a scaffold or a giant ladder but I'm really concerned the electrical box cannot supported the new chandelier.
I went up into attic to see if I could make a support. I followed the conduit which runs between beams but it bends 90 degrees down to box. I can't get my hands down there to feel for support as roof and joists make it too tight. I plan on using a cheap endoscope to see what is attached to box, if anything.
Electricians that I spoke with want to remove some drywall and then put in a support. Either I get drywall patched and painted or I put up a medallion. Both options suck, as I don't want to have either.
I was wondering if I could either drill a hole or use a knockout on the electrical box, feed threaded rod up through box into ceiling and secure it to a piece of metal channel/strut? Strut would span across the joists. Both sides of the rod would have a fender washer and a nut. I think I could get my hands far enough into the area in attic to make this hanger. What do you guys think of this method?  Pretty sure either 3/8" or 1/2" rod could support the weight. Any other ideas? 
Thanks.

You could do whatever you want, but will it hold up 110 pounds is unknown without some specifics as to size of materials and their specifications.  Do you want to trust in "pretty sure" ? This really is something you may want to leave to professionals, who can give some guarantee for their work.

They make a kit for installing fan boxes between joists or rafters though a small hole

how are you intending to reach in there to install the strut?

Start out by taking the old fixture down and examine the inside of the box.  You can probably remove it and see what's up there.

Your ceiling appears to be sloped, and may not be quite planar—is that correct?
